# add a subtitle in my flutter code

Tags: dart, flutter

I have this flutter code :

```
body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: Firestore.instance.collection('Doctors').snapshots(),
          builder:
              (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData)
              return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            return ListView(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
              children:
              snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                return new Card(
                  child: new Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: new Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                          backgroundImage:
                          new NetworkImage("${document['Picture']}"),
                          radius: 40.0,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: 10.0,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          document['Name'],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }).toList(),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
```

and I need to insert another text as a subtitle under the text connected to Text(document['Name'],) but i cant do so, can you help me please

Comment: Have you tried using Column widget?

Answer (score 7):

```
 title: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
    Text(
      "Title",
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16.0),
    ),
    Text(
      'Sub Title',
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 14.0),
    ),
  ]),
```

This is final to use SubTitle in Appbar

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want, simply add [ListTile](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html)

```
body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: Firestore.instance.collection('Doctors').snapshots(),
          builder:
              (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData)
              return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            return ListView(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
              children:
              snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                return new Card(
                  child: new Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: new Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                          backgroundImage:
                          new NetworkImage("${document['Picture']}"),
                          radius: 40.0,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: 10.0,
                        ),
                        new ListTile(
                         title: Text(document['name']),
                         subtitle: Text('subtitle'),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }).toList(),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: thanks I will try one of your edits and see which one suits me more

Comment: well I edited it further more and it became perfect , thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
return new Card(
      child: new Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: new Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            CircleAvatar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
              backgroundImage: new NetworkImage("${document['Picture']}"),
              radius: 40.0,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 10.0,
            ),
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(document['name']),
                Text('subtitle'),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

You can use something like this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to display list of data but I am not sure if you really need card style because your cards does not have gap. 
For your design you can use List Tile which have `leading` for circular image or avatar, `title`, `subtitle` and `trailing` in case you need.
here is an example

```
return new Card(
  child: ListTile(        
    leading: CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
          backgroundImage: new NetworkImage("${document['Picture']}"),
          radius: 40.0,
        ),
    title: Text(document['name']),
    subtitle: Text('subtitle'),              
    ),
);
```

without card

```
return ListTile(        
    leading: CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
          backgroundImage: new NetworkImage("${document['Picture']}"),
          radius: 40.0,
        ),
    title: Text(document['name']),
    subtitle: Text('subtitle'),              
);
```